# How to make a code line dynamic in a Module?

Tags: scoping

The code line

```
If[StreamPosition>0,Read[str,Record]]
```

should be executed in a Module at first.
The Module consists of a Slider and a Pane.
The Slider positions a StreamPosition in file.
The Module then reads a chunk of records from that file.
The external file is a txt file with variable length string records.

The Slider value for the ReadList is just a rough position.
For it is in lack of the knowledge of well defined record start positions.
The unwanted result:
[image]

Therefore the Module has to adjust in a first step to the begin of a
record with Read[str,Record]. The first record displayed in Pane
will be the complete one. 
Should give this result:

[image]

Note: The files start position - it's  1. record - is aligned and
does not need that correction.

[image]

Where to integrate it and
how to bring to life the Read[] in this Module?

```
infil = "F:\\LargeDataSet\\Entwicklung\\Daten Beispiele\\test 1M \
semicolon key.txt";
panerows = 200;
str = OpenRead[infil, BinaryFormat -> True];
filebytes = FileByteCount[infil];
recbytes = Round[filebytes/anzrecs - 2];
erst = 1;
n1 = (erst - 1)*recbytes;  

Module[{},
 Column[
  {Dynamic[SetStreamPosition[str, n1]],
   Slider[Dynamic[n1], {0, maxbyte, recbytes}, ImageSize -> 400, 
    Appearance -> Small],
   Pane[Column /@ Dynamic[ReadList[str, Record, 200 + n1 - n1]],
    ImageSize -> {400, 200}, Scrollbars -> True]}
  ]
 ]
```

Comment: Hi, your code doesn't work when pasted (missing the definitions of `maxbyte` and `anzrecs`, and, of course the file, which is understandable).

Answer (score 2):

If you put `Read[str, Record, 1]` in before, it will align the stream with the next record.

```
Pane[Column /@ 
  Dynamic[ReadList[str, Record, 1]; 
   ReadList[str, Record, 200]], ImageSize -> {400, 200}, 
 Scrollbars -> True]
```

Does that help?  (Tested with `infil = "/usr/share/dict/words"`).

---

If it's a small file, you could preprocess an index of record positions:

```
SetStreamPosition[str, 0];
idx = Reap[NestWhile[(Sow[StreamPosition[str]]; ReadList[str, Record, 1]) &, 
     0, # =!= {} &]][[-1, 1]];

Module[{}, 
 Column[{Dynamic[SetStreamPosition[str, idx[[n1]]]], 
   Slider[Dynamic[n1], {1, Length[idx] - 200, 1}, ImageSize -> 400, 
    Appearance -> Small], 
   Pane[Column /@ Dynamic[ReadList[str, Record, 200]], 
    ImageSize -> {400, 200}, Scrollbars -> True]}]]
```

If it's a large file, you could do it once and store the index in an auxiliary file.

---

Alternatively, for a small file, you can read in the whole file as a `String` and split it into records.

```
db = StringSplit[Import[infil, "String"], "\r" | "\n"];

Module[{}, 
 Column[{Dynamic[n1], 
   Slider[Dynamic[n1], {1, Length[db] - 199, 1}, ImageSize -> 400, 
    Appearance -> Small], 
   Pane[Column /@ Dynamic[db[[n1 ;; n1 + 199]]], 
    ImageSize -> {400, 200}, Scrollbars -> True]}]]
```

Comment: Yes.   .   .It is for very huge files.  .   .I could use your suggestion, modified it and it works well.